# Allow "systemctl halt" for all users? (systemd + debian)

Tags: debian, shutdown, systemd, debian-jessie, poweroff

Is it possible to allow "systemctl halt" for all users?

Currently only the commands:

```
systemctl poweroff & systemctl reboot work on my system (Debian Jessie)
```

When I call systemctl halt as a normal user, I get the following message:

```
Failed to start halt.target: Access denied
```

I tried the following methods:

1. Method - I tried to add a new action in: /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.login1.policy

I copied the action

```
<action id="org.freedesktop.login1.power-off"> to
<action id="org.freedesktop.login1.halt">
```

2. Method (and which worked) was to chmod u+s /sbin/halt 
   but because /sbin/halt is a link to 
   ->  /bin/systemctl 
   this is probably not a good idea

Comment: Note that `halt` and `systemctl halt` are two different commands. Even if one's a symlink to the other, they still behave differently.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Wait several months until Debian Stretch is released – you need at least systemd v227, with commits [2ac3930f](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/2ac3930f5b5fb06c7bd959c2ea8667554fceccfe) (polkit checking for `/sbin/halt`) and [88ced61b](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/88ced61bf9673407f4b15bf51b1b408fd78c149d) (extended polkit data for `systemctl halt` etc.)

Step 2: <del>Create a polkit rule in…</del> Actually, no, that won't be enough because even Stretch still has [polkit v0.105](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=policykit-1), which did not support the JS-based rules yet; only the considerably more limited `.pkla` format. That said, v0.113 is *finally* in "experimental".

But if you happen to upgrade to systemd ≥v227 and polkit ≥v0.113, a rule such as this should work:

```
/* copy to /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/systemd-allow-halt.rules */

polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units" &&
        action.lookup("unit") == "halt.service")
    {
        return polkit.Result.YES;
    }
});
```

---

So, teach yourself to type `systemctl poweroff` instead. "Halt" isn't the normal shutdown command; it's the command to literally *halt* the machine – without powering it off. It's not very useful.

If you do find it useful, use *sudo* instead:

```
# /etc/sudoers

ALL ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl halt, /sbin/halt
```